# Suspend and resume process via signals

Tags: c, linux, signals

I have two problems/questions here!

1) I tried to catch `CTRL+Z` and handle it but nothing happens!!

2) how can i test the SIGCONT ? (it doesn't have a shortcut like CTRL+ ..)

Is there anything wrong with my code? This my code below :

```
void sigstop()
{  
   printf(" Suspended\n");
}

void sigcont()
{  
   printf(" Its Back\n");
}

void sigint()
{ 
    printf(" Interrupt\n");
    //exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){ 
    printf("Starting the program\n");
    signal(SIGSTOP,sigstop);
    signal(SIGCONT,sigcont);
    signal(SIGINT, sigint);
    while(1) {
        sleep(2);
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) I tried to catch CTRL+Z and handle it but nothing happens!!

<kbd>CTRL + Z</kbd> sends `SIGTSTP`. So you need to setup handler for `SIGTSTP` (not `SIGSTOP`). `SIGSTOP` and `SIGKILL` signals can't caught or handled; so your handler for `SIGSTOP` will be ignored.

> 2) how can i test the SIGCONT ? (it doesn't have a shortcut like CTRL+ ..)

Shells typically have a built-in command called `fg`. So once you suspend your process with <kbd>CTRL + Z</kbd>, you'd be able to send `SIGCONT` via `fg`.
But you can always use the shell builtin `kill` (or the `kill` command) to send the desired signal to your process.

---

Couple of other issues in your code:

1. signal function should be of the signal `void func(int sig) { .. }`. So you need to fix your signal functions.
2. `printf` is not [async-signal-safe](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html) and thus it can't be safely called from a signal handler.

Comment: I changed SIGSTOP to SIGSTP, but i keep getting compilation error! 

‘SIGSTP’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘SIGSTOP’?

Comment: It's SIG**T**STP (you're missing a T).